# How to read value in 2 dimensional array?

Tags: vba, excel

In VBA, i have a function to get data and save it in array:

```
Function GetAppro(Current_Sheet As String)

   Dim myArray As Variant

   myArray = Worksheets(Current_Sheet).Range("A3:C6")

   GetAppro = myArray
End Function
```

In other function, i would like read a value in array:

```
Sub GenerateDB()   
  Dim Appro() As Variant

  Appro = GetAppro("Sheet1")
  MsgBox Appro(0, 0) 'Error come from here
End Sub
```

EXcel say me error 9 out of range.

Comment: When loading a range into a range it is base 1 not base 0  so change it to `MsgBox Appro(1, 1)` to get the upper left corner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array index starts at 1 in this instance. Use:

```
Sub GenerateDB()   
  Dim Appro() As Variant

  Appro = GetAppro("Sheet1")
  MsgBox Appro(1, 1) 'Error come from here
End Sub
```

Comment: Shout out to Scott Craner that got in 1 minute before with the same answer.

Comment: Yea, but I was lazy and took the easy way.

Comment: Just to add a some suggestions to be able to resolve these kinds of errors in the future. The way I confirmed the index structure is by adding a break point, for example on your MsgBox, and placing a Watch on your variable in this case `Appro`. Then I could see all the child items and the first one was `Appro(1,1)`. No 0 index items. If you did find my answer useful, unlike Scott I will pander for the fake internet points, so it would be much appreciated if you kindly mark this as a correct answer. Thanks